How to Deploy laravel-react project in shared Hosting?
I have uploaded my laravel react project in shared hosting where there was a laravel site. but i built a new laravel api and frontend in react. my react folders are in resources/js
now when i visit my site it shows 403 forbidden. I also tried by moving .htaccess and index.php to root but not working. Now in front shows 403 and in console it shows
https://anusandhan.news/ 404 (Not Found)Understand this error
tab.js:1 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-kPx0AsF0oz2kKiZ875xSvv693TBHkQ/0SkMJZnnNpnQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

..... For solution i have added in .htaccess
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'sha256-kPx0AsF0oz2kKiZ875xSvv693TBHkQ/0SkMJZnnNpnQ='; object-src 'none';"
    </IfModule>

in resources/views/welcome.blade.php
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Anusandhan News</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    @viteReactRefresh
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/main.jsx'])  <!-- Make sure to point to main.jsx -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script nonce="randomNonceValue">
    // Your inline script
</script>

    <script>
  window.Laravel = {
    csrfToken: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>

